# Remove character from div id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to remove the tag within this div id. What am I doing wrong here?

```
function thanksForHelping(div){
    var siblingOne = $(div).next();
    var siblingTwo = $(div).next().next();
    var NIDsiblingOne = siblingOne.substring(1);
    var NIDsiblingTwo = siblingTwo.substring(1);
}
```

I want to see:

```
siblingOne == #yo
siblingTwo == #hi
NIDsiblingOne == yo
NIDsiblingTwo == hi
```

However I am receiving this error in my console: 
`TypeError: siblingOne.substring is not a function`

Comment: siblingOne is an element and you're trying to call subString() on it

Comment: Thank you for the info- how do I change this into a string so that I may call subString on it.

Comment: `$(div).next()[0].id` should return a string.

Comment: siblingOne.innerText.subString(1) maybe, look into the jQuery API docs

Comment: If you're just trying to remove div, why not do it directly? `$('#theDiv').remove()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.next()` returns a jQuery object ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/next/)), which is why you cannot call `substring()` on it.  If you want the id, you need to use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
$(div).next().attr('id'); // or prop()
```

although it's a little unclear exactly what you're going for, but hopefully this should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you. I need to apply the div variable to a class that has the same div name within it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're saying you have some div like `<div id="#myid">` This is incorrect. You shouldn't have the `#` in the id; that's just how it's referenced in CSS queries.

But, you could be using links to link to that div like this: `<a href="#myid">` in which case you would want to strip the `#` to get the proper value if you were going to target with something like `getElementById()`

Even so, you're calling substring on a jQuery object, not on the id itself. Try something like:

```
function thanksForHelping(div){
    var siblingOne = $(div).next(), siblingTwo = siblingOne.next();
    var existingIdOne = siblingOne.attr("id");
    var existingIdTwo = siblingTwo.attr("id");
    var noHashIdOne = existingIdOne.replace(/^#/, ''); //Using regex here in case it doesn't actually have a leading #
    var noHashIdTwo = existingIdOne.replace(/^#/, '');
}
```

If you were doing the link thing that I mentioned before, you'd have two ways to approach it: 1) Fetch the actual id like I show above, or use jQuery and just use the version with the hash. So, something like this:

```
function elementsForIntraPageLinks(){
    var links = $("a.internal");
    links.each(function(i, link) {
       var href = link.href;
       var targetElement = $(href);
       console.log("targetElement:", targetElement); 
    });
}
```

or without jQuery but in a modern browser:

```
function elementsForIntraPageLinks(){
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]');
    links.forEach(function(link, i, links) {
       console.log("targetElement:", document.querySelector(link.href)); 
    });
}
```

or in a slightly older browser

```
function elementsForIntraPageLinks(){
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a'), i, ii, link;
    for(i = 0, ii = links.length; i < ii; i++){
        link = links[i];
        if (/^#/.test(link.href)) {
            console.log("targetedElement", document.getElementById(link.href.replace(/^#/, ""));
        }
    });
}
```